# How to decode null character, '\0', by base64 command in bash shell?

Tags: shell

I would like to check my test code,

```
$ printf 'A\0B' | base64
```

the output was

```
QQBC
```

To check it, I decoded the coded value above by

```
$ printf 'A\0B' | base64 | base64 -d
$ printf "\n"
```

Then the output was

```
AB
```

The null character, '\0', is missing.

Is this right behavior or do I have a solution to keep the null character?

Thank you very much.

Comment: '\0' is not missing, `printf 'A\0B' | base64 | base64 -d|wc -c` will get the result 3 as expect.

Comment: `printf 'A\0B' | base64 | base64 -d|od -c` will show the right result

Comment: Thank you sigmalha. The result of your way in my environment is 0000000   A  \0   B. Your method shows original '\0' character as it is even after decoding. It is easier to confirm validity of coding/decoding intuitively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The null character, '\0', is missing.

It's there, but invisible. (`\0` is just an input mechanism; it's not what the null character actually looks like.)

To confirm this, you can pipe the output of that command to `less`, which has a special way of depicting control characters.

Comment: Thank you ruakh. I tried your solution and it resulted in A^@B.